# Averaging Shell Script giving errors

Tags: shell

I have a shell script that should take the average of several data files and create a new file. Here is a copy of the script:

```
#! /bin/bash

cat *thist > tmp.dat
> aves.txt
nx=10
ss=5

for i in $(seq 1 $nx)
do
    a=$i*2-1
    export dummy=$(awk 'NR=='$a' {print $1}' tmp.dat)
    awk '$1=='$dummy' {print $5}' tmp.dat > $dummy.dat
    export ave=$(awk 'NR>='$ss' {sum+=$1 b++} END {print sum/b}' $dummy.dat)
    echo $dummy $ave >> aves.txt
done

rm *.dat
```

After reading in 100 .thist files, this is what the output file looks like:

```
0 545.608
4e-07 290.349
8e-07 613.883
1.2e-06 295.655
1.6e-06 310.78
2e-06 305.01
2.4e-06 300.733
2.8e-06 308.319
3.2e-06 298.728
3.6e-06 311.961
```

I am getting an error on lines 1 and 3, as the numbers in the second column should be between 250 and 350. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I have checked all the individual data files and all of the second column numbers are between 250 and 350. I have also run this script reading in only 10 files, and it seems to work just fine. I'm sorry if this is a dumb question or if it's confusing, I'm pretty new to shell scripts. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why not `a=$((i * 2 - 1))`, You can also use `a=$(expr $i \* 2 - 1)`.

Comment: Your errors on line 1 is from the `space` between `#!` and `/bin/bash`. (get rid of it) The line3 error is due to the wildcard `*` in front of the filename (most likely not matching anything). If you have files named `???thist.txt`, you will need to use `*thist.txt`, or if the extensions vary, it will need to be `*thist*`. After you fix line `1` add `set -x` as line 2 for debugging output. Post the actual errors.

Answer (score 1):

Sam, you do not post the actual errors, but it would appear your *line*-`1` error is due to the `space` between `#!` and `/bin/bash` (remove it). Then to enable debugging output add `set -x` as line-2 (or run your script with `bash -x scriptname`, which will do the same thing.) Post the line and actual error that occurs.

Your *line*-`3` error is likely due to no file matching the file glob `*thist`. If there are additional characters that follow `thist` in the filename, you will need `*thist*` (or `*thist.txt` if they all have `.txt` extensions).

You next line is more properly written as `:> aves.txt` (to truncate the file at 0).

Finally your arithmetic should be `a=$((i * 2 - 1))` or not recommended, but you can use the old `expr` syntax `a=$(expr $i \* 2 - 1)` (**note:** you must escape the `*` with `\*`)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I don't think I made my problem very clear. The "error" that I was seeing was in the created aves.txt file. The numbers on lines 1 and 2, column 2, in the aves.txt file are showing up as 545.608 and 613.883, but there is no number in the other text files that are over 350. This script is averaging the *thist files, so I should see numbers like 613. Any thoughts?

Comment: OK, I'm still a bit in the dark. The `aves.txt` file is being created. There is no number in any of the other files over 350, but in averaging those numbers you end up with `545.608` and `613.883` in `aves.txt`, but you should see numbers around `613`? Can you post 3 of your thist files with say 10 lines each so we have actual content to work with. That would help fill in the blanks.